# How can I select newly load html's element?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I have div call `pageBplaceHolder` on pageA.html, in when the user click some functions, a `pageBplaceHolder` will load pageB.html.

```
var menu_request = $.ajax({
    url: pageB.html,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'html'
});
```

In pageB.html, I have a input element id called `inputField`.

So, I would like to have control the `inputField` in the `pageA.html` JavaScript.
For example, I would like to focus it, but I can't do that by using:

```
$('#inputField').focus();
```

How can I achieve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var menu_request = $.ajax({
    url : pageB.html,
    type : 'GET',
    dataType : 'html',
    success : function() {
        $('#inputField').focus();
    }
});
```

Comment: But I don't want to `focus()` it based on a event, for example, a button clicked.

Comment: I didn't get you actually, if you want to focus in future then you should have access to the newly added dom element, in that case you can attach the event by using on() or live() (btw, live is deprecated) or delegate() of jquery, but please check the difference between them before using as their usage may help you to meet your requirement

Answer (score 2):

You can do it exactly the way you described it. All you need to take care of is, that that `<input>` node really has the *ID* of `inputField` and you execute that line *after* it was inserted into the DOM.

Comment: I write it on the head inside the $(document).ready(function(){} in pageA.html, but it seems not success.